# Cannot construct date time from: NO_VALUE (Failure when processing file

Tags: neo4j

I am loading the data from a sample CSV into Employee. The CSV has 2 columns - birthdate and hiredate. The code is like this -

```
load csv with headers from 'file:///northwind/employees2.csv' as row
merge(c:Country {country : row.country})
merge(e:Employee {
employeeId:toInteger(row.employeeID)
  ,firstName : row.firstName
  ,birthDate : date(datetime({epochmillis:apoc.date.parse(row.birthdate, 'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd')}))
  ,hireDate : date(datetime({epochmillis:apoc.date.parse(row.hiredate, 'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd')}))
 })
   create (e) - [:HAS_COUNTRY {countryName:c.country}] -> (c);
```

Getting following error -

**Cannot construct date time from: NO_VALUE (Failure when processing file '/C:/neo4j423/import/northwind/employees.csv' on line 2.)**

I tried with just 1 row in the csv. birthdate and hiredate both are available.
If I try with a hardcoded value like '2001-01-01', the code works just fine.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks

Manoj Joshi

Answer (score 0):

The cypher query language is case sensitive.

So you need to fix the case error:

- `row.birthdate` => `row.birthDate`
- `row.hiredate` => `row.hireDate`

Comment: ah... What a timing. I noticed it about the same time you responded. Thanks so much...!!

Answer (score 0):

My Fault. I was using a wrong column - birthdate instead of birthDate.
Sorry...